# Find if TextBox.Text got changed by the user or by the code (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 project that converts values (i.e.: Celsius to Fahrenheit). There are two TextBox UI elements, one of which is read-only. The user can change the first TextBox to input the value to be converted. He can also press a button to "swap" the two TextBoxes so that he can do the reverse conversion. When the user presses the button, the value from the second TextBox goes into the first TextBox (and vice versa). But it's not the user who changed the value, it's the code who did.

I asked around (on IRC) and researched the subject, but I am a beginner and couldn't understand most of what I have found.

I heard that a simple solution would be to use Data Bindings. I researched the subject, and from what I read, Data Bindings can't solve my problem (correct me if I'm wrong).

I also tried to create a subclass of TextBox, hoping that I could hook in some custom event to it and go further in that direction. But I did not understand how to link the custom TextBox to the UI (in XAML). The way I created the subclass is to just create a new class and add TextBox as the parent. I know there is a template in VS to create a new User Control, and I tried it, but I couldn't understand what I was doing (or what I was supposed to do).

So I have two questions: Am I looking at the problem from the right angle? If yes, how do I create a custom TextBox and link it to the UI? If not, how could I solve my problem?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is how to distinguish if the text got changed by the user or by the code then its simple.

Assuming that when the user types something you'd like to perform method A but when the code changes the text you'd like to perform method B:

In both cases you will need to override the TextBox.TextChanged() event handler.

You will also need a flag variable to tell you if the swap button was pressed or not.

The event handler should be something like this:

```
{
    if (swap_pushed)
    {
        Method_B();
        swap_pushed = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Method_A();
    }
}
```

And finally your event handler for swap Button.Click() should be like this:

```
{
    swap_pushed = true;
}
```